# JavaFX - setStyle() changes not showing

Tags: css, javafx

I am creating a JavaFX application and I am having problems changing the background colors for certain components. For the buttons I am able to change their background radius, but not their background color. For the TableView I am unable to change the background color as well.

Here is my code and a picture of what I am seeing.

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HomeUI extends Application {
    private TableView transactionTable = new TableView();
    private Button importButton = new Button("Import");
    private Button trendButton = new Button("Trends");
    private Button transactionButton = new Button("Transactions");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Set the text of defined fields
        primaryStage.setTitle(" Budget Tracker");
        // Import button information

        // Create Anchor pane
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.setPrefHeight(668.0);
        anchorPane.setPrefWidth(1112.0);
        anchorPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #545e75;");

        // VBox to hold all buttons
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPrefWidth(195);
        vBox.setPrefHeight(668);
        vBox.prefHeight(668);
        vBox.prefWidth(203);
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #82a0bc;");
        vBox.setLayoutX(0);
        vBox.setLayoutY(0);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // importButton settings
        importButton.setMnemonicParsing(false);
        importButton.setPrefWidth(300);
        importButton.setPrefHeight(80);
        importButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #cacC9cc");
        importButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0;");

        // trendButton settings
        trendButton.setPrefWidth(300);
        trendButton.setPrefHeight(80);
        trendButton.setStyle("-fx-background: #bcbdc1");
        trendButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0");

        // transactionButton settings
        transactionButton.setPrefWidth(300);
        transactionButton.setPrefHeight(80);
        transactionButton.setStyle("-fx-base: #aeacb0");
        transactionButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0");

        // Add buttons to the vBox
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(importButton, trendButton, transactionButton);

        // TableView settings
        transactionTable.setPrefHeight(568);
        transactionTable.setPrefWidth(694);
        transactionTable.setLayoutX(247);
        transactionTable.setLayoutY(50);
        transactionTable.setStyle("-fx-background-color: CAC9CC;");
        transactionTable.setEditable(false);

        // Add components to anchorPane
        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(vBox, transactionTable);

        // Add anchorPane to scene and show it
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Buttons

By setting the `style` property, you replace the old style. Doing this multiple times does not combine the styles. You should set a value that combines the rules.

Instead of

```
transactionButton.setStyle("-fx-base: #aeacb0");
transactionButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0");
```

use

```
transactionButton.setStyle("-fx-base: #aeacb0; -fx-background-radius: 0;");
```

#### TableView

`TableView` shows little of it's own background. Most coloring you'll see is the background color of the `TableRow`s that are added as descendants of the `TableView`. You'll need to use a CSS stylesheet to do this though (unless you want to use a `rowFactory` to do the styling).

```css
.table-view .table-row-cell {
    -fx-background-color: #CAC9CC;
}
```